# how to use angular 6 component in react application

Tags: reactjs, angular6

how to use angular 6 component in react application.

I have created an angular component and created a distributed package which i can use it another angular project, how can i use same component in react js apps.

Thanks,
Srinivas

Answer (score 12):

Import a Angular 6 module in React

**Step 1: Configure AppModule for exporting  as a web component from LoginComponent**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [],
  entryComponents:[
    LoginComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(private injector:Injector){

  }

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    const el = createCustomElement(LoginComponent, { injector: this.injector });
    customElements.define('ng-login', el);
   }
}
```

**Step 2: Configure the component**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'ng-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
})
export class LoginComponent {
  @Input() username = '';
  @Input() password = '';

  @Output('login') login = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor() { }

  doLogin() {
    let user = {
      "username": this.username,
      "password": this.password
    };
    this.login.emit(user)
    console.log('emitting event');
  }
}
```

**Step 3: Export as web component**

```js
ng build --prod --output-hashing none
```

**Step 3: Copy below three files from dist/ng-login folder and paste inside ng-elements folder**

```js
runtime.js
polyfills.js
main.js"
```

**Step 4: Open index.html and add the three files**

```js
 <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>

    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./ng-elements/runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./ng-elements/polyfills.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./ng-elements/main.js"></script>
    
  </body>
```

**Step 5: define parameters to pass to the component in react**

```js
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {username:'default-username', password:'default-password'}
  }
```

**Step 6: Add element**

```js
<ng-login ref={elem => this.nv = elem} username={this.state.username} password={this.state.password}></ng-login>
```

**Step 7: subscribe to events**

```js
componentDidMount() {
    this.nv.addEventListener("login", this.handleNvEnter);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.nv.removeEventListener("login", this.handleNvEnter);
  }
```

**Step 8: Display results**

```js
<div>
  User Name: {this.state.username}
</div>
<div>
  password: {this.state.password}
</div>
```

Ref: https://medium.com/@balramchavan/integrate-import-angular-v6-component-s-inside-react-js-applications-da5cc03107b4

Comment: hi i need to use through npm is there anyway using npm

Comment: Just install your npm package, wrap it in an angular 6 component and proceed as described. It is not an easy process and will be a pain to mantain so consider how much time will take you to do a full react rewrite of the component vs implementing it as described.